# Should TL;DR be bold or the sentence that accompanies it?

Tags: user-expectation, text, formatting, legibility

It is quite common on the internet (and commonly used on Stack Exchange also) to use [a short sentence to resume a longer explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn't_read).
There are different ways to express this such as:

> Short answer
>
> ...
>
> Long answer
>
> ... x 100

.

> TL;DR:
>   ...

or simply denoting the point without a title.

The question is what would be **the best solution to benefit the legibility of the text for the user reading it** (I am asking specifically about which part to make bolder/more noticeable):

> **TL;DR:**
>
> The point is this.

vs

> TL;DR:
>
> **The point is this.**

vs

> **TL;DR:**
>
> **The point is this.**

vs

> **The point is this.**

---

In my opinion a resumed idea **should be kept to a sentence or two**, not a paragraph. Also I am referring to resumed ideas, not highlighting of the points through the long answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm hugely in favour of putting a short summary at the top of the article.  This enables me to get the answer in a nut-shell and allows me the choice of whether I want to read through two screens of verbiage to get more detail.

Your first option works best for me.  People using TL;DR seem to come across as geeks who can't afford to spend the time in editing their response to make it clearer from the outset.  Personally, I avoid adding TL;DR blocks if I can help it.

Comment: With the first option you mean "short/long answer"?

Comment: Yes, I was trying to make the point that TL;DR should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Isn't it a matter of wording? As I am not a native speaker it might have some other negative implications I'm not aware of, but I agree the "short answer" looks more elegant. But the question remains, any preference about legibility or reasons about better formatting?

Answer (score 1):

Having large blocks of text (which could be the whole short answer) in bold seems very bad to me. Thus on SE I only bold the TL;DR: part.

(Outside SE I might use a digger font, headers, colour, ....)

Also, not asked, but "TL;DR" is understandable to fewer people than "Short answer". On non-technical sites the latter seems preferable for that.

Comment: I agree on your second part about the "short answer". But what if the short answer is just a sentence, would you keep the rule?

Comment: Generally: yes.  E.g "**Short answer**:<BR>No, that will not work." <BR><BR>**Long answer:** A few paragraphs here with background and how/what/why". Part of that might be that I see the short/long as a header. Even on a site with just plain text.